# daily script to edit markdown files

Tags: python, bash, automation, markdown

I am considering creating a daily script to go through hundreds of Markdown files (on a Mac) and perform simple operations such as:

1. find and replace strings,
2. calculate days elapsed from a particular date and write them in the files,
3. generate reports based on today's date.

I was assuming a Python would be the best option but somebody told me that a bash script using `grep`, `sed` etc is the best solution in terms of speed, being able to scale up, portability etc. What is your expert advice?

1. Python
2. Bash script
3. Performance equivalent for hundreds or even thousands of txt files, so mostly a matter of preference

Thanks!!

Comment: Probably `grep` and `sed` are more eficient (they are compiled binaries), Python will do the job perfectly as well but needs to be interpreted so more computing time is consumed. I use Python all the time for automation tasks, but if you need to save some seconds use the first two.

Comment: Bash will be better IMO. You could do Python too, and I've done it that way. I would just prefer bash in this scenario.

Comment: `awk` can do all the task at hand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on exactly what to replace, meaning how hard the "find" and "replace" operation are to represent -- complex logic should better be managed in a proper programming language like Python.

Complex date calculations are a bit awkward in `bash`, but [can be done](https://serverfault.com/a/279848). Python might be somewhat more readable here.

**Speed**: Likely not going to matter since you are I/O-limited, and only doing it once a day. But if it matters, Python would of course be slower.

**Portability**: Python would be portable to Windows, command line tools like `sed` less so. `sed` would produce shorter code though.

In conclusion, both options are totally appropriate.

Comment: I started to work on this and I wanted to check something: One of my tasks is to count the number of days/weeks from dates in a file: for example replace the text
`- 2021-04-01 {{ ago}}` with `- 2021-04-01 {{25d ago}}`. I made a function `calculateTime` to calculate the days elapsed, but I understand I can't apply it to a sed match like this, correct?
`sed -i '.bak' "s/^- \([0-9]\{4\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}\) {{/&$(calculateTime \1)/g" test.md`
and I should be using `awk`?